# How can I to write unit-test for my android method?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I wrote some code. Now I need to write unit-test for it. I do not know how to write it for this method:

```
    public void parceAuthResult()
{
    NodeList nodeList = baseDocElement.getElementsByTagName("LoginResult");
    if(nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength();i++)
        {
            Element el = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList rootResults = el.getElementsByTagName("a:RootResults");
            if (rootResults.getLength() != 0)
                authResult = true;
            else
                authResult = false;
        }
    }
}
```

baseDocElement and authResult is defined as

```
private Element     baseDocElement;
private Boolean     authResult;
```

some other methods I tested using **junit** and **reflection**

help please, I have no idea how to test that.

Comment: You could refactor the method to return a boolean (authResult) and take baseDocElement as an argument.  Or, create an instance of the parent class in your unit test, set baseDocElement then call parceAuthResult.

Comment: Well lets start out with a method should do one thing, and one thing only. Once your method does one thing its really easy to test, you make a test (or a method) that 'tests' the expected results with the results you get by manipulating the objects/class that corresponds to that method.